# SQL query to find and display duplicates where one of them have a birth year in 2000s and the other one in 1900s

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I am working with table with user ID's but it is not a primary key so it can contain duplicate values and in some cases the birth year is wrong, it is for example 2052 and then user created another account with birth year 1952 which is correct. How to find duplicates so I can eliminate the wrong ones?

I wrote this but it's still not completely what I need

```
select *
  from RF_CUSTOMER a
  join ( select OID
           from RF_CUSTOMER
          group by OID
         having count(OID) > 1 ) b
    on a.OID= b.OID
order by a.oib;
```

Comment: Use a modulus function to strip out the century. The specific function depends on the database you are using. What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using Oracle DBMS

Comment: Which columns do you use to determine if something is a duplicate? Is that only the `OID` column?